# Package versioning with Semantic Versioning for Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, semantic-versioning

I have a composer package A and B. A is for non-Laravel projects, while B slightly extends A with some Laravel specific files (configs, facades, etc).

1. How should B require A? Would it be "^1.1" or "1.*"? As the minor version should not break anything, the second one may be better, as I would not have to update the composer.json of B that often.
2. Then, should B match the version of the Laravel framework (currently "5.6.x")? Is that good or bad practice? Some packages do it that way, other create separate branches for the different framework versions.

Comment: I will suggest fork the repos and add the links in composer.

Comment: Both packages are mine and I provide them in a private composer repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How should B require A? Would it be "^1.1" or "1.*"? As the minor version should not break anything, the second one may be better, as I would not have to update the composer.json of B that often.

That's entirely a policy decision on your part. It sounds like you control both **A** and **B**, so it should be easy for you to make the judgement whether **A** really adheres to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) or not, and the relative risks to **B** for taking every random minor bump from **A**.

> 2. Then, should B match the version of the Laravel framework (currently "5.6.x")? Is that good or bad practice? Some packages do it that way, other create separate branches for the different framework versions.

Never! You're not responsible for versioning Laravel, you are responsible for versioning **B**. **B**'s dependency on Laravel is defined in the package definition. You will likely have the occasion to bump at least the patch level on **B** independently of its dependencies. If you need to make it obvious which Laravel version that **B** is intended for, you can include that at the package name level (**B**-Laravel.X.Y.Z BX.BY.BZ), the build meta data (**B**.X.Y.Z+Laravel.X.Y.Z) or even at the publish/feed level (seperate web pages, REST URI's).

My recommendation is for you to start at 1.y.z and follow the [current SemVer spec](https://semver.org/).

See

- [GitHub:semver/semver/265](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/265)
- [GitHub:semver/semver/352](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/352)
- [GitHub:semver/semver/265](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/385)

Answer (score 0):

If both packages are yours and Private then you can Iclude it in `composer.json`

Here is an example.

```
  "repositories": [ 
    { 
        "type": "package", 
        "package": 
        { 
            "name": "adnanmayo/laralogs", 
            "version": "0.1.4", 
            "source": { 
                "url": "https://repo.url",
                "type": "git", 
                "reference": "master" 
            }
        } 

    }
],
```

You have to also create a auth.json file for credentials access.

```
{
"http-basic": {
    "bitbucket.org": {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "Passwrod"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I fear you've got something wrong. I'd like to now how to version my packages. For example for question 2: Should my package B start with version 1.0.0 or should it always match the Laravel version it's meant for.

Comment: @DoeTheFourth you can specify version and dependencies in your package

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. _Laravel 5.5 Project_ requires _Package B_ which requires _Package A_. Should I version _Package B_ starting with 1.0.0 or like 5.5.0?

Comment: And regarding question 1: Should I require _Package A_ with "^1.1" or "1.*" in the composer.json of _Package B_?